# How to combine selection and assignment in a single Django ORM query?

Tags: django

I'm trying to avoid race conditions when assigning objects from a pool to another object.

```
meerkat_pool = Meerkat.objects.filter(customer=None)
customer.meerkat = meerkat_pool.first()
customer.save()
```

Simultaneous requests result in the same meerkat being assigned to two different customers.

Is there a way to run this as a single database query? [F() expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) would be ideal if I could transform the QuerySet to a single value (e.g. `customer.meerkat = F("first_meerkat_in_pool")`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try **`transaction`**

```
from django.db import transaction

with transaction.atomic():
    meerkat = Meerkat.objects.select_for_update().filter(customer=None).first()
    if meerkat:
        customer.meerkat = meerkat
        customer.save()
```